# Javascript not firing from gridview selected index changed event

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a gridview with rowdatabound set like this:

```
protected void gvStatusActivities_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gvStatusActivities, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
         e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
         e.Row.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");
         //other code...
    }
}
```

I am trying to call javascript (from inside gridview selected index changing event)  to copy row data to clipboard like this:

```
string strScript="<script type='text/javascript'>CopyDataToClipboard('copy text');</script>";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "Msg", strScript);
```

However, the javascript function is not getting called when I select a gridview row. Any help?

Comment: Sorry about the messy looking question above. Posting here for the first time. Thanks.

Comment: I tried doing this:                 e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseup", "javascript: window.clipboardData.setData('text','hi');"); does not work. However, if I do alert('hi');, the alert pops up. Weird.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like works only in IE and not in Chrome. Any cross browser solution? Thanks.